# How to make one dict from comma separated string dicts?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have two string variables:

```
  a = [
{ 
'hash': 'same hash for all photos'
'name': 'test.jpg'
},

{
'hash': 'same hash for all photos'
'name': 'test2.jpg'
},
{
'hash': 'same hash for all photos'
'name': 'test3.jpg' 
}
]


b = [

{

       'Exists': [
     {
       'db': 'main_db'
       'size': 'photo_size'
       'path': 'path'

     },

     {
        'db': 'main_db2'
       'size': 'photo_size'
       'path': 'path'

     }],

'Exists': for another photo

}
]
```

At the end I need one **json**. 'Exists' - is data for each photo, so it's good to append exists to photo. By default they are not str - they are custom *types of data*.

**What I've tried**

I tried to make json string from them using `json.dumps` on str. It works, but I cannot concat them. Create *dict* from *list* and then concat dicts, but `ast.literal_eval` crashes. Concat both strings to one and manually, changing characters create one dict. As a result - error on `json.dumps`.

Is there an easy approach of doing this? Or at least - any ideas?

**Updated**

Output of `print(b)`:

```
[{
    'Exists': [
        {
            'db': 'db_main',
            'size': 5451.0,
            'path': '/www/photos3/'
        },
        {
            'db': 'db_main',
            'size': 5901.0,
            'path': '/www/photos1/'
        },
        {
            'db': 'db_add',
            'size': 4418.0,
            'path': '/www/photos4/'
        }
    ]
}, {
    'Exists': [
        {
            'db': 'db_main',
            'size': 6461.0,
            'path': '/www/photos1/'
        },
        {
            'db': 'db_main',
            'size': 3941.0,
            'path': '/www/photos1/'
        },
        {
            'db': 'db_main',
            'size': 7428.0,
            'path': '/www/photos3/'
        }
    ]
}]
```

About types.

`print(type(b))` - List

`print(type(b[0]))` - zeep.objects.MatchedArray

**Example json outup:**

```
     {
               '1':[{
        'name': ''
        'data_from_exists':[{
    'db':...
    'size':...
    'path':...
    
                            },
    
         {'db':...
    'size':...
    'path':...
    
                            }]
        
        
        }],
'2': and same as first
    }
```

Comment: You can't have 2 Exists key in one dictionary

Comment: In the `b` dictionary you have two `Exists` keys. That is not possible – keys must be unique.

Comment: Oh, I should replace `Exists` with something unique then. `b` - is a data of custom type returned from WCF.

Comment: 1. Your input lists and dicts aren't correct - they need a comma at the end of each entry. 2. What is your expected output for the "one json" you need? What is the connection between `a` and `b`? Are they 1-to-1 with each other for each each item? 3. Consider adding excerpts of your actual lists/data without any important information.

Comment: `a` and `b` connection is: one photo from `a`  -> whole list from `Exists`. They are not correct lists and dicts, because, it's custom data from WCF created on c#. On the exit - any kind of json that could be parsed using `javascript`. I see 2 "fields" on output json - `name` and list from `Exists` with any key.

Comment: What you have as `b` cannot exist in Python. As @HåkenLid has pointed out, 'Exists' repeats as a key for the dictionary. I understand you're saying it's from WCF but what is the output of `print(b)` or `print(dict(b))` or `print(list(b))`? Add that and your expected output to the question; don't describe in comments because the description may not match the actual expectation in code.

Comment: If I understood your expected output correctly, the [2nd option in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66439695/1431750) matches closely with that; but combining them into a list of dictionaries would be better than as a dictionary with incrementing integer-as-string keys. I'd recommend either 1 or 3 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your edits, this is the `a` I'm using:

```py
[{'hash': 'same hash for all photos', 'name': 'test.jpg'},
 {'hash': 'same hash for all photos', 'name': 'test2.jpg'},
 {'hash': 'same hash for all photos', 'name': 'test3.jpg'}]
```

And this is `b`:

```py
[{'Exists': [{'db': 'db_main', 'size': 5451.0, 'path': '/www/photos3/'},
             {'db': 'db_main', 'size': 5901.0, 'path': '/www/photos1/'},
             {'db': 'db_add', 'size': 4418.0, 'path': '/www/photos4/'}]},
 {'Exists': [{'db': 'db_main', 'size': 6461.0, 'path': '/www/photos1/'},
             {'db': 'db_main', 'size': 3941.0, 'path': '/www/photos1/'},
             {'db': 'db_main', 'size': 7428.0, 'path': '/www/photos3/'}]}]
```

For the options below, `a` and `b` need to be the same length. Example data has 3 images in `a` but only 2 'Exists' in `b` so the result will match up for the first two items in each.

#### 1. To create a dictionary `info` of `Name: Exists data`:

```py
info = {i['name']: j['Exists'] for i, j in zip(a, b)}
json.dumps(info)
```

Output is:

```json
{
    "test.jpg": [
        {
            "db": "db_main",
            "size": 5451.0,
            "path": "/www/photos3/"
        },
        {
            "db": "db_main",
            "size": 5901.0,
            "path": "/www/photos1/"
        },
        {
            "db": "db_add",
            "size": 4418.0,
            "path": "/www/photos4/"
        }
    ],
    "test2.jpg": [
        {
            "db": "db_main",
            "size": 6461.0,
            "path": "/www/photos1/"
        },
        {
            "db": "db_main",
            "size": 3941.0,
            "path": "/www/photos1/"
        },
        {
            "db": "db_main",
            "size": 7428.0,
            "path": "/www/photos3/"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### 2. If you want them "together but separate" with an incrementing counter as the key (why?), then you can do:

```py
# Python 3.5 or greater
info = {str(idx): {**i, **j} for idx, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(a, b), start=1)}
json.dumps(info)
```

Output:

```json
{
    "1": {
        "hash": "same hash for all photos",
        "name": "test.jpg",
        "Exists": [
            {
                "db": "db_main",
                "size": 5451.0,
                "path": "/www/photos3/"
            },
            {
                "db": "db_main",
                "size": 5901.0,
                "path": "/www/photos1/"
            },
            {
                "db": "db_add",
                "size": 4418.0,
                "path": "/www/photos4/"
            }
        ]
    },
    "2": {
        "hash": "same hash for all photos",
        "name": "test2.jpg",
        "Exists": [
            {
                "db": "db_main",
                "size": 6461.0,
                "path": "/www/photos1/"
            },
            {
                "db": "db_main",
                "size": 3941.0,
                "path": "/www/photos1/"
            },
            {
                "db": "db_main",
                "size": 7428.0,
                "path": "/www/photos3/"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

#### 3. A more sensible layout of `{image name: {'hash': hash, 'Exists': exists data}}`:

(You can easily modify this to use hash as the main key, instead of name.)

```py
info = {i['name']: {'hash': i['hash'],
                    'Exists': j['Exists']}
        for i, j in zip(a, b)}
```

Output:

```json
{
    "test.jpg": {
        "hash": "same hash for all photos",
        "Exists": [
            {
                "db": "db_main",
                "size": 5451.0,
                "path": "/www/photos3/"
            },
            {
                "db": "db_main",
                "size": 5901.0,
                "path": "/www/photos1/"
            },
            {
                "db": "db_add",
                "size": 4418.0,
                "path": "/www/photos4/"
            }
        ]
    },
    "test2.jpg": {
        "hash": "same hash for all photos",
        "Exists": [
            {
                "db": "db_main",
                "size": 6461.0,
                "path": "/www/photos1/"
            },
            {
                "db": "db_main",
                "size": 3941.0,
                "path": "/www/photos1/"
            },
            {
                "db": "db_main",
                "size": 7428.0,
                "path": "/www/photos3/"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, much more easier, than i tried. Crashes on json.dumps - `TypeError: Object of type Exists is not JSON serializable` (tried first case). `print` output is the same.

Comment: That depends on the functionality of `zeep.objects.MatchedArray` and any other custom types being used in the values/lists. You could first try `b = [dict(i) for i in b]` or something to convert `MatchedArray`'s to dicts. But that's outside the scope of your question/what you were trying to accomplish. Perhaps look into the docs or ask a different question on StackOverflow specifically for that.

Comment: Thanks! It works now. I made dict from `zeep.objects.MatchedArray` (in a very stupid way). And json output is in format I expected. Oh, and thanks for zip library, never heared about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put them into a combined list:

```
new_list = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    new_list.append({'photo': a[i], 'exist': b[i]})

json.dumps(new_list)
```